# Загрузка скрипта JS на страницу в другой кодировке

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

Есть несколько страниц html в различной кодировке (utf-8/windows-1251). На них размещен следующий код, для подзагрузки javascript кода (в utf-8):

```
    help_url="http://eodiwojeidjweo.ru/chat_client/";
    var hcc = document.createElement("script");
    hcc.type ="text/javascript";
hcc.charset="windows-1251";
    hcc.async =true;
    hcc.src =help_url+"chat_client.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(hcc, s.nextSibling);
```

Но! К сожалению на страницах с кодировкой windows-1251, кодировка скрипта js отображается не верно. Хотя пытаюсь явно указать требуемую кодировку: hcc.charset="windows-1251" . Делать две версии js в разных кодировках - плохой вариант. Перевести все сайты на utf-8 - не реально.

Comment: все реально, были бы руки :) Сделать скрипт, который перекомпилирует нужные файлы с одной кодировки в другую, и запустить на нужных машинах???? profit. Дольше прыгать будите с такой ерундой, проще сделать сразу все правильно чем костылять

Comment: Считаю костылем именно ваше решение. Ибо есть штатное решение данной проблемы. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_charset.asp Нужно только правильно его использовать в данном случае. Вопрос в том как?

Comment: Сделать правильно является костылем? Ну тогда удачи. Ваша жизнь ваши проблемы. Лучше решить её сразу, чем усложнять все тегами. И все больше и больше огребать от этих проблем

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь что делать дополнительные скрипты правильней чем использовать 1 тэг

Comment: Дополнительные? вы о чем? вы поменяете у одного скрипта кодировку, и все, другого его не будет. В общем это ваше дело. И если делать не правильно, можно в последствии выстрелить себе в ногу

Answer (score 2):

Иногда бывает необходимо запускать скрипт в utf-8 на странице в win-1251, делается это например так:`<script src="http://www.abc.ru/js/xyz.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>`
`

Comment: Требуется модифицировать именно код который в задаче

Answer (score 0):

вне зависимости от кодировки страницьі
в парметре

```
hcc.charset="utf-8";
```

надо указьівать кодировку в которой отдается файл скрипта.

т.е. тут Вьі указьіваете браузеру с какой кодировки скрипта надо перекодировать в кодировку страницьі клиента.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).